# How is this effect achieved for Chinese characters?

Tags: characters, fonts

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask but I don't know where else to ask.

I'm having some trouble with finding out how to achieve this consistently with Chinese characters. I'm guessing it's some sort of font or variation of the characters but I am unsure how to recreate it with myself with different characters.

找⃣不⃣到⃣源⃣儿⃣滴⃣了⃣，将⃣就⃣一⃣下⃣吧⃣，四⃣周⃣年⃣快⃣乐⃣么⃣么⃣哒⃣，安⃣全⃣抵⃣达⃣厦⃣门⃣咯⃣同⃣学⃣

I've seen it achieved consistently on Chinese websites and I want to use the same effect on an iOS app (I know it's supported as I've seen it used before) and I am wondering if anyone has any experience with getting this same effect themselves.

If anyone could tell me how this is done or provide me with some sort of resource with all the characters in this form, I'd be very grateful.

( "威" "凱" "篠" are the characters I want to put in this form if anyone knows just how to do it, but not actually explain how to!)

Comment: Try Sougou IME, look in 花漾字.

Comment: Could you give an image example of what effect you're looking for?

Comment: @DavidDong I've just realised after flagging the question as "unclear what you're asking" that it displays correctly in Safari (and maybe IE?) but not Chrome. His characters have a rounded square around them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Chinese and can be done with any characters. This is simply a Unicode "effect".

a⃣b⃣c⃣

Simply add Unicode character U+20E3 after the one you want to be enclosed.

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20e3/browsertest.htm